# Find The Minimum Steps to Sort An array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

We are giving A array of size `N` , In one step i can take a element from position `p` and place it **before and after** some other element.
For Ex:

```
A = {3,1,2}
```

I take three and place it before 2 so array becomes `A={1,2,3}`

I need to find the **minimum steps** needed to sort and array in **ascending or descending order**

**My Approach**

Find the number of Inversion that's the minimum steps needed to sort an array.

**Sudo Code**

```
   for i 1 to N:

        Count = Number of Element greater than A[i] from 1 to i
        if(Count>1) steps++
        Update(A[i])

  Similary from Descending

  for i N to 1:
        Count = Number of Element smaller than A[i] from i to N
        if(Count>1) steps++
        Update(A[i])
```

Takes the minimum of both , I can use segment tree for counting element, So overall Complexity **O(N*logN)**

**Problem**

Is my approach is right ? Because i only putting the elements  in only in **one direction** , in problem both direction is allowed (Before and After).
**It will gives me correct Minimum Steps ?**

Comment: Well, this depends on the size of the array and in the more general case, the elements in the array. Take quicksort for instance, it's O(n log n) on average but O(n^2) in the worst case. Whereas mergesort and heapsort are  O(n log n) in the worst case but in practice regarded as slower as quicksort.  So unless you have some prior knowledge about the inputs I'd just go with quicksort (I think I remember there's some empirical proof by Donald Knuth).

Comment: @Sebastian What i am asking is my algo is correct and give me `minimum steps` to sort array not about time complexity

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with inversion.

Let's look at what remains (that is, the elements that were never moved). It's an increasing subsequence. We can also place all other elements wherever we want. Thus, the answer is `n` minus the length of the longest increasing subsequence in the array (for ascending order).

Your approach doesn't work even on your example. If the array is `{3, 1, 2}`, it would print `0`. The correct answer is `1`.

Comment: that's wrong you approach gives wrong answer on this `{1,2,3,1,4,5,6}` answer should one

Comment: @Marvel It gives one for the `{1,2,3,1,4,5,6}`. The longest increasing subsequence is `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`.